# DNS issue 18.04

Tags: dns

Since upgrading to 18.04 from 16.04 I can't connect to websites. I understand with netplan that resolv.conf is no longer used. I can ping all sites with ip addresses and tie into server via ssh. I had to ceate /etc/netplan 01-netcfg.yaml. Which checks out as valid yaml but when I sudo netplan apply I get an error of "Error in network definition //etc/netplan/01-netcfg.yaml line 4 column 15: expected mapping" My yaml is as follows and appears as observed samples.

```
# This file describes the network interfaces available on your system
# For more information, see netplan(5).
network:
  ethernets:
    addresses: "192.168.1.161"
    dhcp4: false
    enp3s0: ~
    gateway4: "192.168.1.1"
    nameservers:
      addresses:
        - "71.242.0.12"
        - "71.250.0.12"
    renderer: networkd
    version: 2
```

What am I doing wrong? Any help would be greatly appreciated. I have limited knowledge of linux so examples are much appreciated. Tom

Comment: I noticed from official documentation that the `renderer` should be just above the line `ethernets`

Answer (score 0):

after ethernets, on next line you have to specify name of your interface, something like

```
 version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
    eth4:
      dhcp4: yes
      dhcp6: False
    eth0:
      dhcp4: False
      dhcp6: False
      addresses: [192.168.110.2/24]
```

Which means your enp3so must go after ethernets and then the rest, properly formatted, you need to add some spaces at the beginning

Comment: I have a fixed ip (shown under ethernets) and it is entered manually without a DHCP and I have disabled IPV6. The name servers are the dns servers issued by Verizon. What would I change to get this yaml to work.

Comment: George, I tried your yaml and got this error "Invalid YAML at //etc/netplan/01-netcfg.yaml line 9 column 16: mapping values are not allowed in this context" What might I have done wrong? Thanks

Comment: This is my new yaml

Comment: # This file describes the network interfaces available on your system
# For more information, see netplan(5).
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
    addresses: 192.168.1.161
    dhcp4: false
    enp3s0: ~
        gateway4: 192.168.1.1
        nameservers:
        addresses:
            - 71.242.0.12
            - 71.250.0.12